# Unkown Index error by using Invantive Control: "The index position 275 is not in use. The last index used is 7"

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

The error is on the column 'whs.description'. It won't give any error at the join 'ExactOnlineREST.Inventory.Warehouses Whs on Whs.ID=SHO.Warehouse'

```
select  Pro.code
,      ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      SHO.Description
,      ItemVersionDescription
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
,      SHO.PlannedDate
,      Whs.description
from   ExactOnlineRest.manufacturing.ShopOrders SHO
join   ExactOnlineREST.Project.Projects Pro on SHO.PROJECT=Pro.ID 
join   ExactOnlineXML.XML.ManufacturedBillOfMaterials BOM on "{" + SHO.ItemVersion  + "}"= BOM.ID_attr 
join   ExactOnlineREST.Inventory.Warehouses Whs on Whs.ID=SHO.Warehouse
Group 
by     Pro.code
,      ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
order 
By     Pro.code
,      ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
```

Comment: *The error is on the column 'whs.description'* That columns seems to exist. What is the error message or problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select Pro.code
,      sho.ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      SHO.Description
,      sho.ItemVersionDescription
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
,      SHO.PlannedDate
,      Whs.description
from   ExactOnlineRest..ShopOrders SHO
join   ExactOnlineREST..Projects Pro 
on     Pro.ID  = SHO.PROJECT
join   ExactOnlineXML..ManufacturedBillOfMaterials BOM 
on     BOM.ID_attr  = '{' || SHO.ItemVersion || '}'
join   ExactOnlineREST..Warehouses Whs 
on     Whs.ID = SHO.Warehouse
Group 
by     Pro.code
,      sho.ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
order 
By     Pro.code
,      sho.ShopOrderNumber
,      SHO.status
,      BOM.CalculatedCostprice
```

This query is structured differently, see for instance " versus ', and use of || instead of +.

On my Exact Online environment this one works.